# Сформировать иерархию ссылок

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть 3 элемента в массиве.

```
$id_array = array(43,42,44);
```

Эти 3 элемента выстроены в порядке наследия. Т.е `43` - это самый корень. 
У каждого из трех этих элементов есть по несколько значений, которые собраны в массивах.

**Я вывожу каждое значение этих трех элементов след.образом:**

```
foreach($id_array as $id){

        $db_query="select n_properties,name_value,translit from ".DB_PREF."base
        where n_properties = ".$id." ";
        list($kolvo_value,$data_value_prop)=obr_db_query_select_assoc($db_query); 

       if($kolvo_value){        
             foreach($data_value_prop as $value){
                echo $value['translit'];
            }
       }

}

43 = array(
'doma',
'dachi',
'kottedji'
)

42 = array(
'kirpichnie',
'blochnie',
'panelnie'
)


44 = array(
'1-komnatnie',
'2-komnatnie',
'3-komnatnie'
)
```

**Ссылки должен получить такие**

```
/doma/
/dachi/
/kottedji/

/doma/kirpichnie/
/doma/blochnie/
/doma/panelnie/

/dachi/kirpichnie/
/dachi/blochnie/
/dachi/panelnie/
```

и т.д по наращиванию

**Вопрос:**  Как мне нужно создать функцию, чтобы полученные значения выводились не просто так, как сейчас, а чтобы к значению добавлялась иерархия в зависимости от родителя, например `link_parent/link1/link2/`  ?  Возможно, изначально исходный массив нужно изменить по-другому, чтобы проще было его разбирать ?
Спасибо !

Comment: я если честно не совсем понял. Есть у вас массив из трех чисел. Дальше что? выбираете какие-то данные. Приведите пример, какие они. И что вы хотите сделать далее с этими полученными массивами. Если приводите вопрос о модификации данных, всегда приводите пример этих данных. И если у вас упрощенный пример, то возможно имеет смысл сделать и полную версию, т.к.  ответ на упрощенный вопрос может быть не самым удачным решением для полной задачи

Comment: каждое из трех чисел массива выбирает свои данные в цикле 
`foreach($data_value_prop as $value)` я их перебираю . 
Из этих данных мне нужна только колонка `$value['translit']`, которая содержит значение url .

Исходя из моего скрипта выводятся все url из трех значений массива:
link1
link2
link3
и т.д

Но мне нужно получить цепочку, исходя из родителя, например 
link1
link1/link2

Comment: дак разве [предыдущий ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720090/223826) не это делает?

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете поменять запрос на

```
$db_query="select n_properties,name_value,translit from ".DB_PREF."base        
where n_properties IN (".join(',',$id_array).") ";
```

И это запрос вернет вам все записи.

Только порядок записей не обязательно будет как в массиве `$id_array`. А дальше массив полученных записей разбирать в цикле, выбирая сначала первый элемент из `$id_array`, потом второй и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как упростить выборку - это не совсем то, что я хотел спросить, т.к массив исходный массив упрощен и на деле будет совершенно другой . Я не могу понять, как осуществить наследие url